# Swing components naming convention?

Tags: java, swing, naming-conventions

Is there any naming convention for swing components such JButtons..? or does any body knows any good way for doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no special convention for swing elements.

The best thing you can do is using names as explicit as possible (as usual).

For my part I try to use the name of the wanted content followed by the type of the component.

For example for a textfield containing an age I would use `ageTextField`.
For a button used to sumbit I would use `submitButton`.

Comment: Isn't this makes name longer?

Comment: I prefer to have longer explicits names than shorter names with hidden senses. As long as the variable isn't named `thisIsMyFieldWhichContainsAnAgeOrMaybeABirthDayFieldText` there is no problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should use common sense. 
I prefer to add suffix to distinguish components, ie. `passwordEdit`, `sendButton`. 
Somebody prefers hungarian notation, but anyway, you should be **consistent** and use same naming conventions through all the code of your project or module.

Answer (score 1):

Hungarian naming convention, though considered bad in general, suits very well for naming Swing UI components.

**Examples:** 

`JButton` for `login` -> `bLogin`, `JTextField` for `name` -> `tfName` etc.

Comment: It's just as bad for all the same reasons.